# How to change displayed names for specific values in a DevExtreme DataGrid column in Angular?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, devexpress

I'm working on an Angular application that utilizes DevExtreme components, and I've encountered an issue with customizing the display of data in a DataGrid component. I have a column named "Type" that displays codes from a database, such as **YPT**, **QRT**, and **QRI**. Instead of directly displaying these codes, I would like the column to display user-friendly names.
Specifically, instead of QRT I want to display "tests", and instead of QRI - "reports". The rest of the codes can be displayed as is.
Here's a snippet of my code related to the column:

```
<dxi-column dataField="Type"
            caption="Type"
            [allowEditing]="true">
</dxi-column>
```

I tried using cellTemplate to achieve this goal but am having difficulty implementing the conditional logic to change the text displayed in the cell. Could someone show me how to properly implement this functionality in Angular using DevExtreme?

Thank you for any help!

I tried:

typescript

```
constructor(
  private dataService: AdministrationService,
  private exportService: ExportService,
  private router: Router,
  private fileUploadService: FileUploadService) {
}



typeLookupDataSource = [
  { code: 'YPT', name: 'YPT' }, // Assuming you want to display 'YPT' as is
  { code: 'QRT', name: 'tests' },
  { code: 'QRI', name: 'reports' }
];
```

html

```
    <dxi-column dataField="Type"
                caption="Type"
                [allowEditing]="true">
      <dxi-lookup dataSource="typeLookupDataSource"
                  valueExpr="code"
                  displayExpr="name">
      </dxi-lookup>
    </dxi-column>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, the best way to accomplish this is the use of dxo-lookup.
This way you can bind a datasource configuration/datastore to the types column and set a display expression.

Link to documentation: https://js.devexpress.com/Angular/Documentation/Guide/UI_Components/DataGrid/Columns/Column_Types/Lookup_Columns/

example: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/broken-worker-96p4lm?file=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html%3A21%2C38

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove allowEditing attribute from  dxi-column and and if need to allow to edit values of column, move it to dxo-editing property.